# How to make switch unswipeable? Or how to set onSwipeListener?

Tags: android, switch-statement, listener

I have a switch `final Switch button1 = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.on_off_switch);`
which has a onClickListener `button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { } );`

Now my problem is, my code executes only when I click on switch, so either I have to make switch unswipeable for user, which seems not very nice solution, or I make it unclickable, but for that I need onSwipeListener.. OR could I make set for my switch onClick AND onSwipe listeners?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Y don't you use toggle button, if you don't want swipe function.

Comment: I didnt mention that I dont want swipe function

Comment: Then what you meant by "How to make switch unswipeable?" Anyways i think you need this for switch `setOnCheckedChangeListener`

Comment: I mean, I'd like to know how to achieve it, because I couldnt find anything in Android reference. Thanks @Kaustuv I'm going to try this methond in a sec.

Comment: @Kaustuv 'button1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() { public void OnCheckedChanged(View v) { } } ); gives me a warning "local method OnCheckedChanged is never used" and it doesnt work, does nothing at all neither onclick nor onswipe.

Comment: I posted the method, how i used it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like this

```
private void setupListenerForSwitches() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(isChecked){
                //do something
            }else{
                //do something
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I dont know why but code above works only with just a small change, line:3 switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener () { ....... when I try to remove CompoundButton it doesnt work... Strange. Thanks for the code.

Answer (score 0):

So you want user switch by swiping instead of click on it?
It's so messy here :P
Because switch extends the Button widget so you can see it, setClickable, setEnable...

Comment: I am afraid you can not set the switch with the swipe listener because the button widget does not support this. One work around is wrap this widget inside a view and assign the swipe listener to that view (view pager for example :) ) Or you can set onTouchListener and in motion event, you can try the ACTION_MOVE for it :D

Comment: I'm just beginner with android and apps at all, thats why it could have been to complicated for me. I just got thing work with Kaustuv's snipet. Anyway thank you for suggestions it may be useful for me in the near future.